# How to disable the edit mode in CKEditor 4? (inline-editor)

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need disable edit mode in inline mode.

I try use this code

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = false;
                var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(elm[0], {
                    extraAllowedContent: '*',
                    toolbarStartupExpanded : false,
                    toolbarCanCollapse  : false,
                    startupFocus: false,                    
                });

                editor.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
                    var ed = ev.editor;
                    ed.setReadOnly(true);
                    editor.removeListener();
                });
                editor.on('focus', function (event) {
                    return false;
                });
                editor.on('blur', function () {
                    return false;
                });
```

This code hide toolbar, but menu (right mouse click) is enable, and I need full disable (readonly mode) only for 'render content' but I need all plugins, including "code" and quote. (if i use render with "removePlugin "toolbar", my plugins code, quote and etc not render my code correct) any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
config.readOnly = true;
```

Ref: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_readonly.html